# Use of FindWindow and window handles within a Windows service

Tags: .net, windows

I've got a third-party vendor who is installing a series of Windows services to a (Windows 2008 R2) server in my control.  Whilst attempting to run each service under its own least-privilege account, we have hit upon obligatory permissions issues.  These only seem to be resolvable by running the service as Local System -- even membership of the local Administrators group is insufficient.

The issue appears to stem from some IPC-related code, which is built around a single .NET class, referenced by the individual services.

As far as I can tell from the IL disassembly (via Telerik JustDecompile), the IPC class derives from `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow` and sets up a `WndProc` override to handle a custom message.

Each service instantiates the IPC class with a given `name` parameter, which it passes as the NativeWindow's *title* and, when it needs to send to the other service, uses the Win32 API `FindWindow` method (called as `Win32.FindWindow(null, targetName)`) to determine the handle of the hidden NativeWindow of the target service, and calls `PostMessage` on that handle, to trigger the remote action.

The issue appears to be that, unless run as Local System, the call to `FindWindow` only returns a zero-handle, which the sending service perceives as the target service not being found.  As mentioned, even when run as a member of Administrators, it still appears to return the zero value.

I thought this might be an issue with Session #0 isolation but, since this is all service-to-service IPC, rather than service-to-desktop, all executables are running in Session #0, anyway.

There's not much I'm going to be able to do about this -- business needs must, after all -- but, from a theoretical perspective:

1. Am I right in thinking a global, named `EventWaitHandle`, with a `while (true) { _h.WaitOne(); /* handle event */ }`-style message loop, on its own thread, is the more-appropriate option for this kind of work?
2. Is this a case of permissions to the window handle (do such things exist?) and, if so, could these be changed (e.g. with `DuplicateHandle`); or does a Windows privilege exist (e.g. in Local Security Policy / User Rights Assignment) that permits/overrides access to the handle?  (I considered SeDebugPrivilege, but local Administrators already *has* that.)
3. Is there anything that documents the inappropriateness of FindWindow/PostMessage for this kind of work (specifically for service-to-service IPC)?  i.e. is this a known limitation for FindWindow, with which I might beat the third-party over the head?

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal restriction in the Windows security model since NT3.x services that only the local service account is allowed access to the desktop when run as a service and it has other restrictions when you select that option.

On Windows Server since about 2003, there is also a service interaction policy you may have to adjust. You may have to reboot the machine to pick up this setting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
```

`NoInteractiveServices` = default is 1 until win2k3, change this to 0. On win2k8+ its default is 0.

This technote below also suggests a method using named pipes to connect a service to a windows app or background task that can run in the logged in session and send materials to the service over the pipe.

Here is a technote from Microsoft on the topic along with some cautions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a registry hack if you want to use a specific account but not sure it will be able to reach into any user's session unless it has admin permissions, I've never tested this use case.

HK Local Machine:

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\your service
```

`Key= "Type"` Position 100h (If you logical 'or' with decimal 256 to set the bit)

Credit for this registry detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4891/Interact-With-Desktop-when-Installing-Windows-Serv